# How to sort in a group with KnockOut JS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am heading to sort each item in each group with KnockOut JS. However, only the group worked and the sorting didn't work as my expectation. Please see my code below with `comment lines` and share me your idea or any guideline.

**CSS:**

```
.displayTable {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100px;
}

.displayRow {
  display: table-row;
}

.displayCell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.displayCell.age,
.displayCell.section {
  width: 50px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="displayTable" data-bind="foreach: choices">
  <div class="displayRow">
    <div class="displayCell" data-bind="text: $data"></div>
    <div class="displayCell">Age</div>
    <div class="displayCell">Phone</div>
  </div>
  <div class="displayRow" data-bind="foreach: $root.people.index.type()[$data]">
    <div class="displayTable">
      <div class="displayRow">
        <div class="displayCell" data-bind="text: name"></div>
        <div class="displayCell" data-bind="text: age"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
ko.observableArray.fn.distinct = function(prop, sort) {
  var target = this;
  target.index = {};
  target.index[prop] = ko.observable({});

  ko.computed(function() {
    //rebuild index
    var propIndex = {};

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(target(), function(item) {
      var key = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(item[prop]);
      propIndex[key] = propIndex[key] || [];
      propIndex[key].push(item);
    });

        // Sort by age in a group
    //propIndex[key].sort(function(l, r) {
    //  return l.age == r.age ? 0 : (l.age < r.age ? -1 : 1);
    //});

    target.index[prop](propIndex);
  });

  return target;
};

var Person = function(name, type, age) {
  this.name = ko.observable(name);
  this.type = ko.observable(type);
  this.age = ko.observable(age);
}

var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  this.choices = ["Friend", "Enemy", "Other"];
  this.people = ko.observableArray([
    new Person("Jimmy", "Friend", 35),
    new Person("George", "Friend", 40),
    new Person("Mike", "Friend", 30),
    new Person("Zippy", "Enemy", 20)
  ]).distinct('type', 'sort');

  this.addPerson = function() {
    self.people.push(new Person("new", "Other", 0));
  };

  this.removePerson = function(person) {
    self.people.remove(person);
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

The result must be:

```
Friend:
George  40
Jimmy   35
Mike    30
```

or

```
Friend:
Mike    30
Jimmy   35
George  40
```

And it also sorts in all other groups.

Here is my [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/huydq1903/gcjd8jhq/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indexes you're trying to sort are object dictionaries not arrays so you'll have to loop through them using a property enumerator. Additionally the properties you're sorting on, "age" in your sample, are observables and have to be unboxed with parenthesis or with ko.unwrap if they aren't always observable.

If you want to used the passed-in sort value to determine which property to sort on I would do something like the following right after the loop that builds the propIndex object.

```
// Sort within groups
for(var i in propIndex){
  if(propIndex.hasOwnProperty(i)){
    propIndex[i].sort(function(l, r) {
      return ko.unwrap(l[sort]) == ko.unwrap(r[sort]) ? 0 : (ko.unwrap(l[sort]) < ko.unwrap(r[sort]) ? -1 : 1);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. As I've tried, it didn't seem to work. This can be a good way for the performance, if we can also sort in the `ko.utils.arrayForEach`?

Comment: @HuyDQ What didn't work about it? Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jlspake/2nk7j5of/)

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. Because I just put the wrong param in the `ViewModel`, it was `distinct('type', 'sort')` instead of `distinct('type', 'age')`. I just corrected it as your jsfiddle and it worked petty well. Thank you very much.